# [SpriteBuilder]App icon become white when use "Assert catalog"

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder, xcode-6.2

I made a test project with :

SB Version: 1.4.7
SB Revision: 10891b8
Xcode Version 6.2 (6C131e)

And export to xcode project.Run that xcode project , everything is fine .App icon show up normally.
After that , i try to use "Assert catalog" , app icon become white when i build the xcode project , and nothing i can do to get old icon comeback.

I attached a screen shot bellow :

[image]

Comment: After searching for a while i founded solution : Delete current Assert Catalog and create new one !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem...
Solution is easy. Just insert "AppIcon" string in info.plist file in /Resources/Platforms/iOS at the Icon file key.